# Получение текста из AutoCompleteTextView в menu

Tags: java, android

Есть menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:sabd="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item android:title="Change"
    app:showAsAction="always"></item>
<item
    app:actionLayout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always"></item>
<item
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always"
    sabd:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:id="@+id/searchItem"></item>
<item android:title="">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/deleteAll"
        android:text="Delete All"
        android:title="Delete All">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        android:title="Settings">
    </item>
</item>

</menu>
```

В этом меню я создаю `AutoCompleteTextView` с помощью `Toolbar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myEditText"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Как** узнать текст из `AutoCompleteTextView`?

P.S. Пытался сделать вот так :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_menu,menu);
        AutoCompleteTextView search = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
        ArrayAdapter adapt = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,namespers);
        search.setAdapter(adapt);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Выходит ошибка :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.x.myfirstnormal.FindSome.onCreateOptionsMenu(FindSome.java:193)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.myEditText); 
String str = autoTextView.getText().toString();
```

Только что проверил, чтобы получить `view` внутри `toolbar`, нужно в `onCreate`

```
 Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);

 AutoCompleteTextView autoTextView = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.my_auto_text_view);
```

После этого можно обращаться к переменной `autoTextView` и вы не получите `null`

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException при использовании этого метода(сетаю адаптер и тут вылетает ошибка).

Comment: Как исправить ошибку?Скинуть код где я вызываю эти методы ?

Comment: @True-hacker ну ошибка возникает, потому что не там ищите вью, она у вас в тулбаре. Попробуйте сначала в onCreate найти тулбаре, а потом, в тулбар, там же в onCreate, найти AutoCompleteTextView, то есть так, ...toolbar.findViewById(...)

Comment: Попробовал вот так вот: Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        AutoCompleteTextView search = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
        ArrayAdapter adapt = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,namespers);
        search.setAdapter(adapt); Не помогло

Comment: Может ошибка потому , что у меня Toolbar не подключается напрямую к моему активити , я беру из toolBar AutoCompleteTextView , а потом в мою менюшку добавляю этот AutoCompleteTextView ?

Comment: Мой ToolBar находится в отдельном файле , не в активити .

Comment: да, так и есть, не знаю возможно ли как-то такое осуществить, подключить тулбар из другого файла. Но если тулбар будет находиться в файле с разметкой активити, то ошибки не будет.  Можете подключить ваш файл с тулбаром в xml файл активити с помощью <include layout="@layout/имя_тулбар_файла"/>

Comment: Если я подключу к файлу тулбар ,  то AutoCompleteTextView создаться заново только в другом месте . Но ведь есть кучу приложений в меню которых есть edittext(или AutoCompleteTextView ) и всё прекрасно работает . Пример https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pdfm_6W7sc3RYWMaGLYR6JF0bPRlIiyqOp8J0bLPeijJBThOkWUXuy3Ac3bqWOPz9Q=h900-rw